# jQuery mobile, Unwanted div appears inside form

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

My question is why another div appears right infront of my submit button, and note that this div acts as a button aswell, but it doesn't do anything when clicked. However if you click my submit button it will function and the div will disappear, but if you refresh the page it will reappear again.

```
<form method="post" action="newsfeed.php">
    <p>
      <label for="input1">Rubrik:</label><br>
      <input id="input1" class="text" type="text" name="rubrik">
    </p>
    <p>

    <label for="textarea-a">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea-a" width="550px">
    </textarea></p>
        <input type="submit" name="doSave" value="Send" ></input>
</form>
```

I have no clue what is wrong. I inspected the element through my webrowser and found that jquery mobile translated my code to this

```
<form action="newsfeed.php" method="post">

    <p></p>
    <p>
        <label class="ui-input-text" for="textarea-a"></label>
        <textarea id="textarea-a" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" width="550px" name="textarea"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="ui-submit ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" data-disabled="false" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner"></span>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-a">
            <input class="ui-btn-hidden ui-input-text ui-body-a" type="submit" value="Send" name="doSave" data-disabled="false"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So it creates two extra divs and one span. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jquery Mobile converts form inputs (among other things) on page load to make a mobile friendly version of it.  Usually this is desired, as buttons are easier to click with the jquery mobile version of it.  If you do not want this add the data-role="none" attribute to your submit input like this:

```
<input type="submit" data-role="none" name="doSave" value="Send" ></input>
```