# Changing value of submit button in jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery

I want to change the value (displayed text) of a submit button with jQuery 1.4.5:

```js
$('.filter_watch').change(function() {
      $('#filter_submit').val("New text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brand" class="filter_watch">
  <option>change</option>
  <option>me</option>
</select>

<input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="Suchen" data-theme="b">
```

I also tried:

```
$('#filter_submit').prop("value", "New text");
```

The change function fires as it logs the event, but the button text will not change. I tried a couple of varions as found on SO, but non of them had any effect.

The problem seems to be, that the submit button value is changing, but the text on it is set within the div due to jQuery mobile.

After rendering and change event the button looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
   Suchen
   <input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="New text" data-theme="b">
</div>
```

What could be the reason for this and how can I change the value?

Comment: Is `preventDefault` a standalone function you defined? If not, an error will be thrown. And what is `.button('refresh');` meant to do? (You should also provide `<option>`s if you want a `change` event to be triggerable)

Comment: Your question was about how to change the value/text (not clear which you wanted) of a button.  The provided code *minus unrelated errors* does this as requested using `.val("new text")`.  You would see this if you had created an [mcve] (ie without the unrelated parts).   Please identify what problem you are actually having.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I initially tried .val('new text') but as it did not work I tried different other suggestions found on SO. None of them works. While I can see that the minimal example works and also I can set other values within the form, I am not able to change the lable within my project.

Comment: @freedomn-m I edited the question and added the rendered code, which makes it more clear why it is not working.

Comment: Did you try changing that text as well? `$('#filter_submit').parent().text("New text")`

Comment: Funny, this will remove the entire button and write "New text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that *jquery mobile* is changing your button to a "more mobile friendly appearance" - by wrapping it in a div.

As asserted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23071466/2181514

> Jquery Mobile converts form inputs (among other things) on page load to make a mobile friendly version of it. Usually this is desired, as buttons are easier to click with the jquery mobile version of it. If you do not want this add the `data-role="none"` attribute to your submit input.

Alternatively, you can use jquery to update the text node by looking for `.contents()` with `.nodeType==3`:

```js
$('.filter_watch').change(function() {
  $('#filter_submit').val("New text");
  var t = $('#filter_submit').parent().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
    if (t[i].data.replace(/[\n\t]/g, "").trim() !== "")
      t[i].data = "New text";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brand" class="filter_watch">
  <option>change</option>
  <option>me</option>
</select>

<div>
  Suchen
  <input id="filter_submit" type="submit" value="Suchen">
</div>
```

(jquery mobile classes removed in the snippet to show both the div and the button text changing)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.
Are you trying to change the text on the button specifically on jQuery 1.4.5?

if so - you need to make sure you add every script as told in jQuery [website](https://jquerymobile.com/download/)

Basically, you need to add this to your header part of the html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already added this and the site is working. It is even changing the value of the button, but not the text  "Suchen".